# Permission not asked on release version of app. Debug version works properly

Tags: debugging, flutter, permissions, release

I have this app that I did as a practice where I use the path_provider and sqflite. The problem is that when I am on debug mode, in emulator or actual device, even without asking for permission the app works well. However, when I install the "release" version, I get an error on the list that I populate. My hunch is that it is because there is something wrong with accessing the database so I added asking permission, still not working on "release" version. Kindly help enlighten.

```dart
  @override

  void initState() {
    requestWritePermission();
    super.initState();
  }

  requestWritePermission() async {

    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.WriteExternalStorage);

    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.authorized) {
      setState(() {
        _allowWriteFile = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Additional info. I am certain that the permission is not working because aside from there is no actual asking of permission, I also display a blank container with "permission denied" if the permission is not accepted.

Comment: Please add some code if possible.

Comment: I've added the code. That's pretty much it. It is working on debug but when i install the release version, it won't work.